# Sql Server Analysis Services 2008 Totals

Tags: ssas

I am using Sql Server Analysis Services 2008 to build a cube. I have the following scenario and was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to accomplish it. The cube is displayed over the web using a third party tool(Active Analysis). There is role based security so the user only see's their data. I am trying to allow the user to see their data, and also a total of all the other data. For example, the user currently only has access to see the total population of Massachusetts, but should also see a row below it with the total population of all states.
                           **Year**
**States**                   2009            2010                   2011 
**MA**                       1,000,000.00        1,050,000.00        1,102,500.00 
**All States(?)**      365,000,000.00      383,250,000.00      402,412,500.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the role and on the Dimension Data tab, you probably have Enable Visual Totals selected which prevents the user from seeing the total of all states. When you clear the checkbox, the user still sees only MA but the total should be all states.

Comment: That was very helpful information and I think solved part of my problem but I am still stuck on how to create the dimension member "All States". I know the totals are shown within the cube browser with the summation of all the states but that total is not sent to the third party tool I am using. I think the totals are specific to the cube browser. Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can either send the totals of all states over to my third party tool(Active Analysis), or the alternative would be to create a new dimension member "All States" with the totals.

Comment: You can create a custom member on the Calculations tab of the cube designer. Let's say your dimension is [State] and the attribute is [State]. When you create the calculation, set the Parent Hierarchy to State.State. Set the Expression to something like this: Aggregate([State].[State].[State].members)

Answer (score 0):

complementing Stacia's answer because it may be tricky to understand:

- Visual Totals = true -> see only the totals permitted to the user
- Visual Totals = false -> see the big total even though it may
  restricted some part because of permissions

[image]